# MySQL - Condensing queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm self taught when it comes to MySQL and I'm not sure what is the proper way of doing something like this:

```
$type1_sql          ="SELECT * FROM type1 WHERE type1_id=$type1_id";    
$type1_res          =mysqli_query($handle_db, $type1_sql);
$type1_row          =mysqli_fetch_array($type1_res);
$type1_name         =$type1_row['name'];

$type2_sql          ="SELECT * FROM type2 WHERE type2_id=$type2_id";    
$type2_res          =mysqli_query($handle_db, $type2_sql);
$type2_row          =mysqli_fetch_array($type2_res);
$type2_name         =$type2_row['name'];

$type3_sql          ="SELECT * FROM type3 WHERE type3_id=$type3_id";    
$type3_res          =mysqli_query($handle_db, $type3_sql);
$type3_row          =mysqli_fetch_array($type3_res);
$type3_name         =$type3_row['name'];
```

Is it better to do what I'm doing; query everything individually, or is there a way to condense all of this into one query?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: If the queries aren't related and they are serving different purposes, and there's no way to combine them then it's fine.  Except you don't need to query `*` all records if you're just using `name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important: Take into account that although @Alp's solution might be what you're looking for:

```
(SELECT name FROM type1 WHERE type1_id=$type1_id)
UNION
(SELECT name FROM type2 WHERE type2_id=$type2_id);
UNION
(SELECT name FROM type3 WHERE type3_id=$type3_id);
```

It will remove any duplicates that might be found, for instance, if `$type1_id` is equal to `$type2_id`. If you want to fully select all results (including duplicate rows) you should run this (removing unnecesary parentheses):

```
SELECT name FROM type1 WHERE type1_id=$type1_id
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM type2 WHERE type2_id=$type2_id
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM type3 WHERE type3_id=$type3_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the column `name` for each of the tables you can use a `SELECT UNION` query:

```
(SELECT name FROM type1 WHERE type1_id=$type1_id)
UNION
(SELECT name FROM type2 WHERE type2_id=$type2_id)
UNION
(SELECT name FROM type3 WHERE type3_id=$type3_id);
```